# hijack get_template_part via plugin

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to do a plugin that will change the behavior of a theme.

In the theme file I have a get_template_part('libs/templates/user_menu');

I want to make my plugin to "force" the get_template_part return another slug file (a path to a file in plugin folder).

So far this is my code inside the plugin:

```
function wpse21352_template_part_cb( $slug )
{
   if(slug == 'user_menu') {
     return WP_PLUGIN_URL.'/'.$slug;
   } else {
     return $slug;
   }
}

do_action( "get_template_part_user_menu", 'user_menu' );
add_action( 'wpse21352_template_part_cb', 'get_template_part_user_menu', 10, 1 );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, `get_template_part` does not return anything. It loads a file from your theme based on the parameters you pass to it. The function does not support filtering, which means you can not actually overwrite what is outputted by `get_template_part`.

The only thing the action `get_template_part_[slug]` allows you to do is output something *before* the theme file is loaded. For example, using

```
function myplugin_before_login( $slug, $name ) {
    echo 'Example';
}

add_action( 'get_template_part_login', 'myplugin_before_login', 10, 2 );
```

would output "Example" before the loading the theme file when calling `get_template_part( 'login' );`.

### Actions and filters

In general, however, I believe you might misunderstand how actions and filters work. The [WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API#Hooks.2C_Actions_and_Filters) offers extensive information on their use and usage.